# Putting extra round brackets - code fails to compile

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I have a function that returns a boolean

```
bool func_true()
{
    // do some stuff
    return true;
}
```

Now actual code call this like this

```
if (auto err = func_true())
{
    // some stuff
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << err << '\n';
}
```

All good till this point. If I put an extra round bracket around my call, compilation fails:

```
if ((auto err = func_true())) // doesn't compile!
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << err << '\n';
}
```

GCC Error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'auto'
 if ((auto err = func_true()))
      ^~~~
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/812424bfdb66eec3

Is this a gcc bug, or I am doing something stupidly wrong?

Comment: You can't declare variables in an expression.

Comment: Normally, you can't define variables in the middle of an expression like that. E.g. you can't do `cout << ((int x = 5) + 1);` or `someFunction(const char *foo = "hello world");`. But *as a special case* you *can* put a variable definition as an `if` condition. But nothing says you can put a variable definition in parentheses as an `if` condition. (You'll find that you can't put parentheses around a normal variable definition either, such as `(int i = 5);`)

Comment: Why would you want to add redundant parentheses?

Comment: @EJP I wanted to do something like this  ((auto err1 = func1()) && (auto err2 = func2()))

Comment: Well...what's wrong with old `if (func_true()) {}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax (according the latest C++ standard, ISO/IEC 14882:2014) of an [`if` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is as follows:

> `if` `(` *condition* `)` *statement* [`else` *statement*]

The syntax for a a *condition* is as follows:

> *expression*
>
> `[` *attribute-specifier-seq* `]` *decl-specifier-seq* *declarator* `=` *initializer-clause*
>
> `[` *attribute-specifier-seq* `]` *decl-specifier-seq* *declarator* *braced-init-list*

Now the code `auto err = func_true()` matches the second form on the condition, specifically, `auto` matches *decl-specifier-seq*, `err` matches *declarator* and `func_true()` matches *initializer-clause*

But the code `(auto err = func_true())` can't match the second or third forms of *condition* as `(` cannot start an *attribute-specifier-seq* nor a *decl-specifier-seq*, however it can start an *expression*

To which the syntax is:

> [ *expression* `,`] *assignment-expression*

Now if you follow the syntax definitions, you will find that `auto` cannot start an expression (an identifier can, but `auto` is a keyword, so not an identifier)

To put it simply, GCC's behaviour is correct, it is a syntax error.